# Concatenate Strings with Do Loop with dynamic column and files

Tags: vba, excel

So at Assign sheet I indicate the sheets to take data for each group (each for column and the first row is the explanation of the group). I dynamically can add res at the file or delete

After I use predefined codes to assign which type of discounts / day are applied. At the example I only put two codes (C and S) and one week. For example the raw sheet data for designations Red and Black.
[Data product worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENC30.png)

Then at Diary I want to show the result of concatenate the B1 value (name of product) each time code fromm price are indicated into the rows. Also I use two loop because at raw product data I have one column for price but at the Diary I have two
[Summary page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdefu.png)

This is what I finally want to get and doing like that because my boss don't know anything for code and he wan't edite it so I try to do ll dynamic at the sheets :) [I only put two images because i don't have reputations point enough to put more]

With the formula I only get FALSE as answer :(, and I need to get what you can see at summary page

```
   Sub Diary()
        Dim I As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer, n As Integer
        Dim p As Integer, d As Integer, f As Integer
        Dim a As String, b As String
        Dim element As Variant
' Initialize variables I and y at 3 and 4 to begin to show the data at the column I desire. Also x and z were intended to pass the one column mode data sheet to the two column mode at the summary page.
        I = 3
        x = 1
        y = 4
        z = 0

        With Worksheets("Asign")
            .Activate
            .Range("B2").Select
        End With
' Set the size of Data with sheet names it get form the page assign. It can dynamically changed as size as names of sheets
        With ActiveSheet
            r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        Dim Data() As String

        ReDim Data(r)

        For p = 1 To r - 1
           Data(p) = ActiveSheet.Cells(p + 1, "B").Value
        Next p

        With Worksheets("Diary")
            .Activate
            .Range("C7").Select
        End With
' At Diary concatenate the same cell for all the sheets I have his name stored at Data() and then pass to the next cell with data at raw data sheets (in the images (Red, Black ,... pages). In this case search for code S 

        Do
          Cells(7, I).Select
           ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(" & a & ")"
            For Each element In Data
               b = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "IF(Data& !R[-2]C[" & x & "]=""S"",CONCATENATE(Data&!R1C2,"", ""),"""")"
               a = b & ";" & b
            Next element

            x = x - 1
            I = I + 2
        Loop While I < 4
 ' The same for the second column of summary sheet called Diary. In this case search for code C    
        Do
          Cells(7, y).Select
           ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                                   "=CONCATENATE(" & a & ")"
           For Each element In Data
              b = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "IF(Data& !R[-2]C[" & z & "]=""S"",CONCATENATE(Data&!R1C2,"", ""),"""")"
              a = b & ";" & b
             Next element

             z = z - 1
             y = y + 2
          Loop While I < 4
  ' Drag and Drop the formula to all the sheet's cells you need
        Range("C8:E8").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C8:E10"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    '
    End Sub
```

Comment: some of what you wrote is getting lost in translation.  it is not clear what you are asking to do..  .... please include an example of how the final data is obtained.  .... it is unclear what _Madrofor_ is  .... attach a screenshot of what you are trying to do, if possible

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I try to explain myself, I EDIT the post in order to clear it.

Comment: it is not an inconvenience    .... what is Madrofor ?

Comment: So the macro is to automate the cells' formula in the Diary sheet ? Why not use macro to do the string concatenate and write directly the result in Diary's cells ? Just add a button called "update me" for your boss ... the macro will be easier.

Comment: Well, it just too long to read and understand what your problem.  Could you specific your problem, like sample data, what it output now, and what it should be.  Moreover, remember to provide sample in text format, so we can test it before post as answer

Comment: @Prisoner, the OP attached pictures

Comment: @Proger_Cbsk I can do that ? I didn't know, I´m just starter with vba and learning myself at home.... How I do that or what function I must search in order to learn to do it ?. Many thanks for your response

Comment: @Prisoner sorry I edit the post to do it shorter :( I hope it was clear now ... If you need aclaraciones don't hesitate to ask. Thanks for read it, any help will be appreciated

Comment: @jsotola Maybe you want to take a look: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1050927

Comment: That's better.  But I can't understand your code, you have for each loop with `element`, but never use in the loop; Assign formula before it assign (`a = b & ";" & b`); And what you try to do with `a = b & ";" & b`?

Comment: @Prisoner I try to add comments at code to clarify ... Hope it works :)

Comment: Try to post your table as text, you may use this [tool](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) to help you.  And your comments cannot answer my question.  Note: I'm not the owner for this tool, credit to 'senseful'

Comment: @Judith, simply do a `ActiveCell.Value = a` in your example . Direct concatenation is done like `ActiveCell.Value = a & b & " hi! " & ...`

Comment: @Proger_Cbsk Thanks for your proposal but when I added it I get only the first row and not all complete and get only: False;False value at the cell (whatever are the value  from r, the number of sheets it must concatenate). I don't know how overpass this False;False value and the limit to two concadenation. I hope you can provide any suggestion ... Anyway very thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

try this.   .... could be simplified by looping through "colors" .... black, red, etc

```
Sub Diary()

    Dim red As Variant
    red = Sheets("red").Range("d6:g12")                 ' put range data into an array for processing

    Dim black As Variant
    black = Sheets("black").Range("d6:g12")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Dim strC As String
    Dim strS As String

    For i = 1 To 7
        For j = 1 To 4

            strC = ""
            strS = ""

            If LCase(black(i, j)) = "c" Then strC = "Black"

            If LCase(black(i, j)) = "s" Then strS = "Black"

            If LCase(red(i, j)) = "c" Then
                If Len(strC) > 1 Then strC = strC & ";"
                strC = strC & "Red"
            End If

            If LCase(red(i, j)) = "s" Then
                If Len(strS) > 1 Then strS = strS & ";"
                strS = strS & "Red"
            End If

            Sheets("diary").Range("c7").Cells(i, j * 2 - 1) = strS
            Sheets("diary").Range("c7").Cells(i, j * 2) = strC

        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ! I check it but only works for Red and Black worksheets. If it's possible what I need is that I can add/remove dynamically sheets at the assign page. I try to add Color page for example and it didn't work.... I'll try to work in your code and thank you.

Comment: `it didn't work` is not a description of a problem .... what did you try ?  ... what error did you get?  .... what was the undesired result?

Comment: what is the reason for filling the _Diary_ that way?  .... there may be a better way to present information.

Comment: Sorry i explain myself badly . It concatenate all the values is perfect. But only for Black and Red sheets. I need. That for all the sheets my boss put at one specific column at Asign Sheet. The idea is he can put there 24 - 25 names, change it without need to enter at code. That is the reason to use Data() and name1 to n variables to store the sheet names. I hope I explain myself better and apologize for not be clear before.